# Loading XML from unknown location on Classpath in Java

Tags: java, xml, classpath

I want to load an XML into my java program from my classpath using a URL.

```
     URL resource = MyClass.class.getResource("test.xml");
     File file = Paths.get(resource.toURI()).toFile();
```

The catch is that I want to be able to do this without giving the full path to the xml file. How can I properly add the XML to my classpath to test this. I thought I added it correctly as an external folder but I'm getting a null pointer exception indicating that it was not added properly or that I can't actually search for it.

Comment: The full path wouldn’t work, regardless.  The argument to getResource is not a file name, it’s a relative URL, whose base is each entry in the classpath.  So, what is your classpath?  And what is the name of the package containing MyClass?

Comment: C:\MyWorkspace\Project1\Source\Java\org\Package1\MyClass.java where org\Package1 is the package

Comment: The Class.getResource method expects the specified name to be in the same package.  Is test.xml in an org/Package1 directory?